# Pandas DataFrame not working - need to filter_by json key which is a date

Tags: python, json, pandas

This JSON data has a date for the key and I would like to filter by it but  I'm not sure how to achieve this. I have tried other scenarios on the web but they did not work. Thanks for your help in advanced. Here is my code below.

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
import json

url = "https://www.recreation.gov/api/camps/availability/campsite" \
      "/90329?start_date=2020-11-01T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&end_date=2021-12-31T00%3A00%3A00.000Z"
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()

js = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))

filter_by = ['availability']
df = pd.DataFrame(js)
df = df.filter(items=filter_by)

print(tabulate(df, headers=filter_by))
```

Here is the output from my code.

```
availabilities         {'2020-11-01T00:00:00Z': 'Not Available', '2020-11-02T00:00:00Z': 'Not Available', '2020-11-03T00:00:00Z': 'Not Available', '2020-11-04T00:00:00Z': 'Not Available', '2020-11-05T00:00:00Z': 'Not Available', '2020-11-06T00:00:00Z': 'Not Available', '2020-11-07T00:00:00Z': 'Not Available', '2020-11-08T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-09T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-10T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-11T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-12T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-13T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-14T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-15T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-16T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-17T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-18T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-19T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-20T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-21T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-22T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-23T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-24T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-25T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-26T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-27T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-28T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-29T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-11-30T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-12-01T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-12-02T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-12-03T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-12-04T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved', '2020-12-05T00:00:00Z': 'Reserved',
```

This is how I would like to output to be.

```
Date                      Available       
--------                  -----------  
2020-11-01T00:00:00Z    Not Available       
2020-11-02T00:00:00Z    Not Available
2020-11-03T00:00:00Z    Not Available
2020-11-04T00:00:00Z    Not Available
2020-11-05T00:00:00Z    Not Available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

1. `json_normalize` to convert to df,
2. Then replace the column names that start with `availability.availabilities.` - this is because of the output from `json_normalize`,
3. Then remove columns that start with a non-numeric character, basically anything that;s not a date
4. Finally transpose it and rename the columns :

### Code

```
js = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
df = pd.json_normalize(js)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('availability.availabilities.', '')
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains(r'^[a-z]+')]
df = df.T
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Date', 'Available']
print(df)


                     Date      Available
0    2020-11-01T00:00:00Z  Not Available
1    2020-11-02T00:00:00Z  Not Available
2    2020-11-03T00:00:00Z  Not Available
3    2020-11-04T00:00:00Z  Not Available
4    2020-11-05T00:00:00Z  Not Available
..                    ...            ...
192  2021-05-12T00:00:00Z           Open
193  2021-05-13T00:00:00Z           Open
194  2021-05-14T00:00:00Z           Open
195  2021-05-15T00:00:00Z           Open
196  2021-05-16T00:00:00Z           Open
```

Comment: WOW, thank you very much for the quick answer it worked perfect.